# Issue I can't solve in the SimpleBlogReader Windows 8 tutorial

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am following the tutorial located here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465045.aspx

In the section about styling the application they want you to insert some Xaml in the ResourceDictionary

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowsBlogBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF0A2562"/>
<Style x:Key = "WindowsBlogLayoutRootStyle" TargetType = "Panel" BasedOn = "{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowsBlogBackgroundBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

However, the compiler gives me these errors:

error WMC0035: Duplication assignment to the '_Items' property of the 'ResourceDictionary' object

Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content.

Anyone have any ideas as to whats going on here?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing the closing block for SolidColorBrush in your example. Is it in your Xaml file?

Comment: You are not providing enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowsBlogBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF0A2562" />
                <Style x:Key="WindowsBlogLayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowsBlogBackgroundBrush}"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- 
                Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
             -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml">

            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

this is just working fine i have tested it a layout grid.